# Dial into a device using Java and a modem?

Tags: java, hyperterminal

Short background, I have a device I connect to via HyperTerminal to receive information about the current state of the device. The device is connected to over modem with settings of 2400,7,O,1. I then send a single command and read the returned data.

My question is, is there a away in Java to dial out, once connected send the command and store the returned data in a string? Or can someone suggest a better alternative.

My end goal is to set a schedule for this to run and have it email the returned results.

I have attempted to search the site and have not found what I am looking for.

Comment: Seemed pretty clear to me that he wanted to know how to talk to a modem using java...

Comment: Thank you, I was rather confused why this got closed.

Comment: Great Question, I needed that. How did the answer below work out for you?

Comment: I only was able to get it to work with a direct serial connection. I could not get the modem to communicate correctly. Which did no really help my send goal.

Comment: @jer.salamon Great question. Had you any success on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I beleive you want to use the Java Communications API...

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html

This also looks helpful...

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/31915

Also, if I recall correctly the way to tell a modem to dial is to send it "ATDT" and then the number... but I haven't done that in about 15 years now :)

Oh hey, this looks handy too :) http://www.uic.edu/depts/accc/network/dialin/modem_codes.html